# Make lighttpd load vhosts live?

Tags: lighttpd

My site lets people add their own vhost entries that all point to the same directory, but are handled differently by a PHP script. The domains are stored in a MySQL table and are loaded when lighttpd starts, by automatically running a python script referenced in the lighttpd config file.

But obviously when someone adds a new vhost, it only works after I manually restart lighttpd. Is there a way to make lighttpd check for new vhosts, or read them live?

I thought of making a script that checks periodically for new vhosts and restarts lighttpd when a change is detected, but that's probably a bad thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is already a module for that: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModMySQLVhost